Why can't I register my code snippet after running it a few times?
I used proxy IP, stealth to set parameters, and uc mode of selenium base, but I still couldn't register after running it several times. Not even changing mailboxes. Where do you think the problem is?
Where do you think the problem is?
def input_content(driver,user,name,password,number,email):
    common_xpath = '(//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section account-info-section"]/div[@class="container-xs centered"]/div[@class="form-table"]//div[@class="column large-6 medium-6 small-6"])'
    driver.type(f'{common_xpath}[1]//input', user)
    driver.type(f'{common_xpath}[2]//input', name)
    random_birthday = str('01012001')
    driver.type('(//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section account-info-section"]//div[@class="row"])[2]//input',
                random_birthday)
    email='dsdsaimx@gamil.com'
    number='18801928001'
    # email
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[1]',email)
    # password
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[2]', password)
    # password
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[3]', password)
    # number
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[2]//input)[1]', number)

def open_url():
    proxy='user:password@host:PORT'
    driver = Driver(uc=True,proxy=proxy)
    stealth(driver,
            languages=["pl-PL", "pl"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )
    url = "https://appleid.apple.com/"
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 7)
    driver.click('(//nav[@id="ac-localnav"]//div[@class="ac-localnav-menu"]//li)[2]/a')
    driver.sleep(5)
    # driver, user, name, password, number, email
    input_content(driver,'adimmx','daimmx','cixjzrnw@V25','1232','213')
    driver.sleep(100)
    driver.quit()


Could you edit the question to specify details on what you did/ran to register and what errors you were getting when you couldn't register?
